# The Website: http://cnpj.info/2609063 don't work curl or wget (Bash Script)

Tags: bash, shell, curl, libcurl

The command wget or curl didn`t work for website: http://cnpj.info/2609063 and can not return the webpage code.

```
curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: br,gzip,deflate Host: cnpj.info Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3 --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36' -X GET "http://cnpj.info/0101000"
```

We have tried the wget http://cnpj.info/0101000 but nothing is working properly.

We expect to return the webpage in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I noficed two problems with your script.

1. Missed single quote (') after header fields.
2. After fixing this one you will get gzipped html text. Piping curl output to gunzip will give desired result.

Try following:

```
curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: br,gzip,deflate Host: cnpj.info Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'
 --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36' -X GET "http://cnpj.info/0101000" | gunzip -
```

Comment: Incorrect return:

<h1>GDPR and cookie notice for EU visitors</h1>
This site respects visitors privacy and does not collect any personal data, but uses cookies exclusively to display (1) this message once a day for EU visitors and (2) to display <a href="/omniboxbusca.html">omnibox usage hint (in Portuguese)</a> for all visitors viewing the third page with CNPJ data.

Comment: The return look a blocked code isn't the content of page.

Comment: When running the code in my answer I got ~10K html file. Looking at this file with browser, I see exactly the same as at  http://cnpj.info/0101000.

BTW this site has limit on number of requests per day.

Comment: Use `--compressed` instead of hard-coding the `Accept-Encoding:`header, and do one `-H` for each header to set, not all at once.